# How to get corresponding ideavim action name for an action?

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

How can I get corresponding ideavim action name for a particular action? For example, in the screenshot, I want to find corresponding ideavim action name, so that I could map using a vim keybinding. `map <leader>f <action> <action-name-here>`
[image]

actionlist for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

We can use the keymapping to see the one to one relation between idea action and ideavim action

For example:
[image]

In this screenshot, we can see keymapping is `control+shift+down` (If you don't have any keybinding set, then add a keybinding temporarily and later remove it, if you want to). You should be able to get the same keybinding in `:actionlist` as well (see [using actionlist](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim?tab=readme-ov-file#finding-action-ids)). Search for `<C-S-Down>` or case insensitive `<c-s-down>`, using `:actionlist <c-s-down>` ideavim command, and you should be able to get the corresponding ideavim command.

[image]